# The name 'Component' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am following this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) on how to build an Mvc component.
when i try to call it from the viewpage, using

```
@Component.InvokeAsync("WFActivities")
```

i got the error

> The name 'Component' does not exist in the current context

I can't find the namespace were this component class is located either on documentation or in foruns.

Comment: Which MVC version are you using? Probably not Core.

Comment: You have to do `@await Component.InvokeAsync()`. But yeah this only works in ASP.NET MVC Core, not older MVC.

Comment: I am using mvc 5. Guess i have to stick with partial views.

Comment: Or child actions. View components superceded child actions in Core. The methodology for invoking them is different, but they're similar in function.